# use the same method for two different events?

Tags: vb.net

So basically I've got three listboxes containing items. I want the items to be deletable, so for this I've got a ContextMenuStrip with only one item : Delete. Though, I'd like the items to be deletable, too, via a press on the Delete key. So i've got my code, that you can see here :

```
    Dim TempList As New List(Of String)
    For Each Trigger In ListBoxTriggers.SelectedItems
        TempList.Add(Trigger)
    Next
    For Each Trigger In TempList
        ListBoxTriggers.Items.Remove(Trigger)
    Next
```

It's a little longer because there is data related stuff but now this is the part concerning the removing from the ListBox. Now, for this I've been using

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItemTriggers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SupprimerToolStripMenuItemTriggers.Click
```

(supprimer means delete in French). But the thing is I'd like to process the

```
Private Sub ListBoxDescription_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ListBoxDescription.KeyDown
```

in the same method. But I can't since e is not the same type... I of course can copy the same code in both handlers but that's not really... clean. I can, too, just create another method that I'll call in both ases like

```
Private Sub ListBoxDescription_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ListBoxDescription.KeyDown
    Delete()
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripMenuItemTriggers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SupprimerToolStripMenuItemTriggers.Click
    Delete()
End Sub
```

But I don't really like it neither... doesn't look like the most efficient solution...

Is there anything I can do for this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you don't like the last solution? There's even a special menu for this in Visual Studio. Refactor->Extract Method

Comment: @Steve I think that, without add-ins, Refactor is only available for the C# editor.

Comment: @AndrewMorton right, it is a pity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyEventArgs` derives from `EventArgs`, so you can declare

```
Private Sub ListBoxDescription_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBoxDescription.KeyDown
```

and if you actually need `e` as KeyEventArgs then you can use

```
Dim kea = DirectCast(e, KeyEventArgs)
```

Also, if your delete method has a signature like

```
Sub DeleteThings(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

then you can do

```
AddHandler ListBoxDescription.KeyDown, AddressOf DeleteThings
AddHandler ToolStripButton1.Click, AddressOf DeleteThings
```

Note that you do not need a `Handles` clause when using AddHandler.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to write the common event handler similar to this:

```
Private Sub CommonEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles ToolStripMenuItemTriggers.Click, ListBoxDescription.KeyDown
    If sender Is ListBoxDescription Then
        Dim kea = DirectCast(e, KeyEventArgs)
        If kea.KeyData <> Keys.F2 Then Exit Sub
    End If
    '' Common code
    ''...
End Sub
```

Works fine, pretty hard to win elegance points with it however.  You might as well move the `Common code` into a separate private method.  The usual advice is to treat whomever is going to maintain your code some day as a homicidal maniac that knows where you live.